# The Recruitment Office Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction

> Eight People A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are sitting in a straight line, all of them facing the same direction (say North). Each one of them has passed a recruitment exam and must join the office on different months viz. January, February, March, April, May, June, July and August but not necessarily in the same order.
>
> G sits third to the right of the person who joins in May. The person who joins in August sits second to the right of G. A and E are immediate neighbors of each other. Neither A nor E have joining dates either in May or August. Neither A nor E is an immediate neighbor of G.
>
> H sits third to the right of the person whose joining date is in January. Neither A nor E join in January. H's joining date is not in August. Only two people sit between E and the person whose joining date is in July.
>
> The person whose joining date is in February sits to the immediate left of D. Only one person sits between E and B. C joins on one of the months before July. E joins after April. G joins the office after A.

Now the Question,

**If H is related to 'July' in a certain way based on the above arrangement and B is related to 'June' following the same pattern, Find out Who is related to 'May' following the same pattern?**

<sub>P.S. I don't claim this puzzle to be mine. I read it in a newspaper and liked it. So, I have posted it here. I couldn't find it on the internet.
Source- The Indian express</sub>

Comment: How can E join after April if H joins in July, E doesn't join in May or August and B joins in June?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I think "related to" means something in terms of the seating arrangement, i.e "H sits 3 to the left of the person joining in July and B sits 3 to the left of the person joining in June" or similar. I hope sure Sid can verify.

Comment: "Related to" doesn't mean "Joins in"... Jonathan Allan is right when he says it is related to the seating arrangement..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The final seating arrangement is:

> `A  E  C  B  F  G  H  D`
>  `3  6  5  1  7  4  2  8`
>
>  where letters are the persons and numbers the months. **H** sits two to the right of the person starting in July and **B** sits two to the right of the person starting in June, so the question is: Who sits two to the right of ther person staring in May? and the answer is **F**.

The first paragraph leaves us with ...

> `.  .  .  .  .  G  .  .  .  .`
>  `.  .  5  .  .  .  .  8  .  .`
>
>  We take **G**'s place as fixed, but we dont know yet how much the seats extend, so at the moment there are ten seats instead of eight. The both places next to **G** can't bei **A** or **E** and the two places with months assigned can't be **A** or **E**, either.
>
>  **A** and **E** are adjacent, so they must either be left of **5** or right of **8**.

The second paragraph leaves us with ...

> `.  .  .  .  .  G  .  H`
>  `.  .  5  .  1  .  .  8`
>
>  **H** sits three to the left of **1**. The **1** can't be directly to the right of G, because that would mean that **H** is in one of the right seats (of the 10-seat arrangement), but these are taken by **A** and **E**. Likewise, **1** can't be in the two leftmost seats (again, of the 10-seat row), because that also must be **A** or **E** if anything and we are told that neither **A** nor **E** start in January.
>
>  That means that the one goes directly to the left of **G*. It also means that the two righmost chairs (of our hypotheti 10-seat row) are not used.

The rest of that paragraph means that ...

> `A  E  .  B  .  G  .  H`
>  `.  .  5  7  1  .  .  8`
>
>  There are two people between **E** and **7**. Because **E** is either in the first or second seat, that pattern must be 'E . . 7`. There is only one possibility to make this and also the condition that there is only one person between **E** and **B** fit.
>
>  The rest is easily filled in by using the hints in the last paragraph about who joins before/after someone else or before/after a certain date.

Comment: Brilliant, +1, Answer accepted...

Answer (score 2):

Full Arrangement:

> A(3)  E(6)  C(5)  B(1)  F(7)  G(4)  H(2)  D(8)

Final Answer:

> "F" (two to the right of the month)

Work: (Mostly 1st Paragraph)

> .  .  .  G  .  .
>  5  .  .  .  .  8
>
>  Missing both A&E which as a pair which can't touch G, nor be 5 or 8, and are thus either left or right of display.

Work: (Mostly 2nd Paragraph)

> H can't be 8, nor can he be left or right of what was shown, nor can he be 3rd to the right of A&E.
>
>  .  .  .  G  H  .
>  5  1  .  .  .  8

Work:

> One person sits between E and B.  G+H prevent this to the right.
>  Two people sit between E and 7.  5+1 force location of E & 7.
>  E=6 because it's excluded from being anything else.
>  A  E  .  B  .  G  H  .
>  .  6  5  1  7  .  .  8

Work:

> C isn't 7 or 8 so it must be 5.
>  2 is next to and left of D
>  Unshown is G joined after A.
>  A  E  C  B  .  G  H  D
>  .  6  5  1  7  .  2  8

And my apologies about the formatting of this.  I haven't figured out how to have it be both spoiler'ed AND monospace.